# Detecting errors in HTML syntax notepad++

Tags: html, notepad++

Is there any plugin for notepad++ to detect HTML errors

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Untitled Document<title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class=the_class>
   <span>
  </div>
   </span>
 </body>
<html>
```

Comment: Is there a particular error in the HTML you posted that concerns you?

Comment: recommendation of tools is off-topic here. by the way, you do need a HTML validator. Official one is [here](https://validator.w3.org/nu/)

Comment: @DanLowe No i can fine the errors if i'm looking for them but sometime we all forget to close a tag or 2 and at times can be a pain I was just wondering if there was an easier way

Answer (score 2):

Source Forge has an HTML tag plugin here --> http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/

You may also find this Syntax Validator useful. --> http://esprima.org/demo/validate.html

The web based validator below is a bit of a pain, as you can not copy and paste into the validator. Hope this helps!

(Apologies ahead of time for link-based answers.)